Enforcing tokens per minute rate limit in FastAPI
I'm developing FastAPI endpoints that rely on calls to OpenAI's chat completion. Some of the calls use asyncio.gather to make concurrent requests to OpenAI. Because of this, I'm worried about rate limits. I'm currently using Semaphore to limit the requests per minute, but I'm not sure how to handle tokens per minute.
I've thought about creating a global variable that holds the token capacity, but I don't think that would work since the app will utilize multiple workers and I'm worried about race conditions. Are there any design patterns that could help my case? (FYI I don't want to have to use a database to hold the current token capacity.)

Please, add a minimal reproducible example with the code you have attempted to implement. This is not a place for people to write code from scratch to you.
If you  have a simple "hello world" script with a view you want to rate limit, people can make suggestions to you. hardly otherwise.

That said, you will have to use  a common resource where all workers can communicate and update data so other workers can see. That can be done with a relational database but will be easier with a realtime NoSQL thing that can hold key/values and execute atomic operations - like  "KeyDB" (a replacement to formerly opensource "Redis")
